# Facebook oauth2 API refresh tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am building an application that does not have a client interface.

At the setup step: The user logs into the server throught a browser once using oauth, and the server makes sure that the client is identified.

From this point on, no browsers are invlovled. It all happens in the background.
It then keeps acting on behalf of the user for as long as the user can be validated.
That means that once in a while, my server needs to call the oauth provider to validate the user still exists.
Until now, I have only used google oauth: Once in a while, I would call the refreshtoken api, and get a new token indefinitely from the server side. (you need to ask for "offline access" when you get the user token).

Now I would like to use facebook as well, but reading their APIs, I see no mention of a possibility for a server to refresh it's tokens:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/
It looks like it all has to be done from the client device.
As I have no client device, does this mean that I cannot write this sort of app with facebook?

Comment: You are correct. When the token is not valid anymore the user needs to go through the browser to get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your scenario can be covered through Facebook's mechanism. But you need to support a re-login if some error occur while using long lived access token. This can happen due to security measure taken by Facebook (ex:- data breach, cryptographic breach) or when user revoke tokens or change password or when tokens are not used for a longer time.

Steps to follow (According to their docs),

1. [Obtain a User access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens)

   These are short lived

   > Short-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about an hour or two
2. [Exchanging Short-Lived Tokens for Long-Lived Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/#exchanging-short-lived-tokens-for-long-lived-tokens)

   These have life span of around 60 days, even when they are not used.

   > long-lived token generally lasts about 60 days.

Basically, once you obtain a long lived token, you can use it from the server application. During this process, you required a client which used browser only to obtain short lived access token.

But as previously mentioned, these tokens can expire,

> These tokens are refreshed once per day, when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers. **If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new token.**

So you will require to obtain new ones by going through above two steps.

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the problem. What do I do after 60 days? The user will lose access to my app...

Comment: _“What do I do after 60 days?”_ - you notify the user that their access token has become invalid (or is about to), and that the will have to “visit” your app again to create a new one. _“The user will lose access to my app...”_ - if they can’t be bothered to perform a tiny little action every two months, then what your app does for them probably couldn’t have been that important to them to begin with.

Comment: Rather than worrying only about requiring a re-login after 60 days of inactivity, you need to worry about user's ability to revoke tokens and also about possible token revocations by Facebook. All this is there to protect end user data. So your app also require to adhere to them.

Comment: @04FS This is not a mobile app. It is a device without a screen who's backend needs to validate your account once in a while. I have no screen to display a "please login" message. The best I can do is to send you an email on another device. Spamming the user with emails on another device, which requires you to login is a terrible user experience.

Comment: @Kavindu I don't understand what revokation has to do with this? Refresh tokens take care of revokation. If my backend has the ability to refresh the token every 60 days, that's exactly when I know if the user refreshed my token.

Comment: @eshalev well, you have the choice between that terrible user experience … and not doing it at all. Facebook does not allow apps to perform actions in the name of the user for all eternity any more, that was just abused too much. So you can either provide a way for the user to generate a new access token by sending them through the login flow _somwhere_, or … say goodbye to your app idea.

Comment: @04FS there is no need to say goodbye to anything. The product already exists and works with the other big oAuth providers. I was just surprised that unlike every other big company, Facebook does not support backend refresh tokens. It seems like a common enough use case. I posted this question because I thought I misread the docs... Sort of expected FB to have the same level of APIs as Google/Microsoft/Any other internet giant.

Comment: Facebook used to, but doesn’t any more. All your other “giants” simply did not play such a big role in influencing the last US election … so they didn’t have to make such drastic changes either.

Comment: Also, as far as I can get from docs, refresh validity works in a sliding window, this is highlighted by "*These tokens are refreshed once per day, when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers*" section. But I haven't tried that myself