# Using a Google API refresh token from the backend

Tags: google-signin, refresh-token

I have a web-app with a backend which needs to call google APIs on behalf of the user (from the backend).

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

This means that I get the user to log on once from a browser, and from then on, the user never opens the browser again.
I plan to have my backed request a refresh token.
After that, I will run a cron Job that periodically refreshes old tokens **from the backend** .

With some other APIs (such as FaceBook), I see that acquiring new tokens a backend will be considered a DDOS attack. They really want token acquisition to happen in the browser alone. [Facebook oauth2 API refresh tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843902/facebook-oauth2-api-refresh-tokens/54859212#54859212)

I really need to make sure that this is not the case with Google, and that my use case is supported:
So: Can I make Google access-refresh calls from my backend on behalf of millions of users without abusing Google's TOS, and getting banned? (I realize that I will need a paid plan)